# Mozilla Parser for screen scraping

Tags: java, dom, parsing, screen-scraping, mozilla

I'm writing an app that takes in HTML code of a page and extracts certain elements (such as tables) of the page and returns the html code for those elements.  I'm attempting to do this in java using the Mozilla parser to simplify the navigation through the page, but I'm having trouble extracting the html code needed.

Maybe my whole approach is wrong, aka Mozilla parser, so if there are better solutions, I'm open to suggestions

```
String html = ///what ever the code is

MozillaParser p = // instantiate parser


// pass in html to parse which creates a dom object
Document d = p.parse(html);

// get a list of all the form elements in the page
NodeList l =  d.getElementsByTagName("form");

// iterate through all forms
for(int i = 0; i < l.getLength(); i++){

    // get a form
    Node n = l.item(i);

    // print out the html code for just this form.
    // This is the portion I haven't figured out.
    // I just made up the innerHTML method, but thats
    // the end result I'm desiring, a way to just see
    // the html code for a particular node
    System.out.println( n.innerHTML() );
}
```

Comment: Using the  mozilla parsing engine is pretty heavyweight for what you are doing. Just an observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla parser seems like overkill here, I've used [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) with some success for just the type of thing you are doing.

Comment: Yea, this looks like a good option.  I was getting the feeling that Mozilla was a little too much

Answer (score 1):

I've had a measure of success using htmlcleaner (http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/): it's pretty quick and has options to let you determine how "strict" it should be. I try to avoid html scraping wherever possible, though, for all the obivous reasons (data exposed via REST or other form of API tends to be more reliable, legal, easier to parse etc.etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I have coded an HTML wrapper with Javascript on Mozilla platform. I pack the codes into two extensions to Firefox browser. One, called as MetaStudio, is a data schema definition tool which annotate Web pages semantically. The other, called as DataScraper, is a tool to extract data snippets from Web pages and formatted them into XML files.

All source codes are readable. Please go to http://www.gooseeker.com to download them.